# Windows Workflow Foundation Pause By Id

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible to Pause a running workflow if the only information I have is the Id of the process?

```
        workflowApp.Run();
        var workflowId = workflowApp.Id;
```

My requirement is that I have a web app where multiple users can start and pause processes, and the id of the processes will be stored in a database.

As far as I can tell I need a reference to the `System.Activities.WorkflowApplication` to pause the application as follows:

`workflowApp.Unload();`

How can I call `Unload()` to pause a running process if all I have is the Id of the running process?

I've noticed that an entry for a process is only added to the `[System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancesTable]` when calling the Unload() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a WorkflowApplication to run a workflow you are responsible for managing it. You can use the WorkflowServiceHost if you want to delegate that responsibility and use the Workflow Control Endpoint to unload or suspend a workflow instance by id.

Comment: Thanks Maurice...I'll investigate how to do that with the WorkflowServiceHost

Comment: Basically you need to create workflow services and use WCF messaging to start new and interact with existing workflow instances.

Comment: are you aware of any examples that show how this is done using a very simple workflow? I'm struggling to find any concrete examples where anyone can select from a list of running workflows and pause/resume them

Comment: See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx) page under **Figure 52: Self-hosting the workflow service**